# Small delay when executing MacOS terminal commands

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I've noticed that there is a small but noticeable delay when I execute simple commands like ls and cd in the terminal. Can anyone tell me how to go about troubleshooting this problem? I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Do you have a special prompt (show the output of `declare -p PS1`)? Do you have set any traps?

Comment: When i run that command I get:    declare -x PS1="[\\u@\\h \\W\$(__git_ps1 \" (%s)\")]\\\$ "

Comment: But it was a long time ago I changed that.

Comment: At each prompt you execute the command `__git_ps1`, I suspect that's the reason for the delay. Change the prompt temporarily using `PS1='$ '` and check if the delay is gone. If `__git_ps1` really is the cause, then you probably cannot do much about it other than disabling it.

Comment: That actually worked, thanks. Don't know why it suddenly caused that delay since I've been having it like that for a while.

Comment: [`__git_ps1`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L300) does a lot of stuff. It's runtime depends on your git config, current git repository, and more. Changing one of these things also changes its runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of the discussion in the comments:

At each prompt you are executing the command [`__git_ps1`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L300) which creates a small delay. The time needed to execute `__git_ps1` depends on your `git` configuration and your current working directory.

To get a faster prompt you could

- improve the script `__git_ps1` to run faster (probably not a real option).
- use a simple prompt that does not show all the information given by `__git_ps1`.
- use a timeout such that `__git_ps1` is used only if it's not too slow (see following section).
- run `__git_ps1` only when something changes (not explained here since you would have to identify all commands that could change the output of __git_ps1).

#### Use a timeout

In `bash` the command `timeout n cmd` executes `cmd` for at most `n` seconds. When used in your prompt

```
PS1="[\\u@\\h \\W\$(__git_ps1 \" (%s)\")]\\\$ "
```

becomes

```
PS1="[\\u@\\h \\W\$(timeout 0.2 __git_ps1 \" (%s)\")]\\\$ "
```

You can adjust the timeout to your needs.

Comment: To check if PS1 is running something (besides `__git_ps1`) you can run this simple test: `set -x; cd;`. If it's running some function or calling some command you should be able to tell from the output. Of course, after you are done run `set +x`.